# jQuery dynamically add images to table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add images to a given table. I have the following code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" id="game"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function table() {
    var i,
        x,
        domRow,
        domCol,
        rows = $("#rows").val(),
        colums = $("#columns").val(),
        table = $('<table>'),
        cellId = 0;

    table.empty();
    for(i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        domRow = $('<tr/>');
        for(x = 0; x < colums; x++) {
            domCol = $('<td/>',{
                'id': "cell-" + cellId++,
                'class': "cell",
                'text': 'cell',
                'data-row': i,
                'data-col': x
            });

        domRow.append(domCol);
        }

    table.append(domRow);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Now I want do add images to each data cell from **another function**. 
Example:

```
function images() {
    var game = $("game");

    // TODO the images need to be added too
    game.append(table())
}
```

An image with the name 0.png needs to be added to the data cell with the id="cell-0" and so on... (1.png to id="cell-1")

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery `append` method can take a function that returns the HTML string to append. And within that function `this` refers to the element. So you can just find all the `td` elements in your table and append the right image to each one:

```
function images() {
    var game = $("game");
    var tableEl = table();

    tableEl.find('td').append(function () {
        // `this` is the <td> element jQuery is currently appending to
        var num = this.id.split('-')[1];
        return '<img src="' + num + '.png" />';
    });

    game.append(tableEl)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `window.myTable` or similar to the output of `table()`, and then edit the table by acessing it from `window.myTable`.

For adding the images, what I would *instead* recommend is just inserting:

```
var img = $('<img>');
img.attr('src', parseInt(cellId) + ".png");
img.appendTo(domCol);
```

Right before `domRow.append(domCol);` (I did not test this).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code to add your images in each cell that its id correspond.

```js
$('[id^=cell-]').each(function() {
  var curCell = $(this);
  curCell.html('<img src="' + curCell.attr('id').substring(5) + '.png">');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td id="cell-0">1</td><td id="cell-1">2</td></tr>
</table>
```